# Struggling with string to list conversion

Tags: python, string, list

I have been given the input in string format:

```
"""4
101,CS101,10
101,CS102,20
102,CS102,30
102,CS101,10"""
```

I want to convert it to a list in a format

```
[["101","101","102","102"], ["CS101","CS102","CS102","CS101"], ["10","20","30","10"]]
```

I tried using zip but could not do it.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The solution you  accepted is not very good, it is very specific to YOUR case, it uses loops where it shouldn't and iterate over content uselessly, and regardint the other answer the not the best at all, would you consider giving argument for this choice ? Consider also the other users that'll pass by and will think that is good code practice whereas it isn't

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the rows, then use `zip` to read in th other way by pairing each row :

```py
v = """4
101,CS101,10
101,CS102,20
102,CS102,30
102,CS101,10"""

rows = [row.split(',') for row in v.splitlines()[1:]]
cols = list(zip(*rows))

# rows [['101', 'CS101', '10'], ['101', 'CS102', '20'], ['102', 'CS102', '30'], ['102', 'CS101', '10']]
# cols [('101', '101', '102', '102'), ('CS101', 'CS102', 'CS102', 'CS101'), ('10', '20', '30', '10')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
s = """4
101,CS101,10
101,CS102,20
102,CS102,30
102,CS101,10"""

l = s.replace('4','').replace('\n', ',')[1:].split(',')
cols = [l[n::3] for n in range(int(len(l)/4))]

#[['101', '101', '102', '102'], ['CS101', 'CS102', 'CS102', 'CS101'],
#['10', '20', '30', '10']]
```